Enforce Permission Requirements Defined on Built-In Apex Classes Used as Inputs - Spring 25
There is release update planned for the next year:
Enforce Permission Requirements Defined on Built-In Apex Classes Used as Inputs 
I did several different tests - in user context, system mode, with permissions like CRUD, for Custom, Standard objects, subflows ran from master flow in system and user context, I was checking apex behavior and dml operations, in user mode, checking permissions... cannot find example with the issue mentioned in release updates notes.
One of my last test scenario:

Flow in SystemMode, User does not have permission to run reports.
Flow ask about report Id (provided public raport Id)
Flow executes apex class which accepts reportId
Apex class runs raport using ReportManager.runReport

I checked the bahavior for Release Update in both cases - Activated/Deactivated. Flow was tested via Debug with selected user but also via Action Button. I expected that with Realease Update deactivated permission wont be checked... But it was verified by system in both cases.
Who knows steps to reproduce or example of such test to reproduce mentioned behavior with release update disabled and enabled? (I already checked some other threads, responses but I see that understanding of the impact of this update is not very common).

Given this hasn't gotten any traction.. If you have support access raise a case and make salesforce clarify it.
